# ASP Identity via a web service layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am rather new to MVC and ASP identity, I would like to have my MVC application connect to a web service for user management.

From the examples I seen and read for ASP identity all connect directly to the database which is what I want to avoid is there a way to configure asp identity to connect via web service?

For example could i install ASP identity on the web service and have the web application connect to it for user management?

Thank You

Comment: It makes no sense to use the identity mechanisms if the users are stored externally.
What you want is OAuth.

This means that your external application manages the users and you only need the mechanism of OAuth and ClaimsIdentity in your application.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is federated identity.

Answer (score 0):

Look at OAuth Libraries for .NET:
https://oauth.net/code/dotnet/

I worked by OWIN Middleware as a client,
also, you can run an OAuthServer and make a separated layer for user management.